# Linq to XML selecting a node bases on a attribute value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that returns a set of elements that are unique by a attribute value. This presents a problem, as I can not select a node by its name:

```
<doc>
    <float name="score">1.2873721</float>
    <arr name="2_category">
        <long>3021</long>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_FamilyName">
        <str>Some Cookbook </str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_IsFamily">
        <str>0</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_SellPrice">
        <str>49.95</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_VendorId">
        <str>ABC</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_VendorName">
        <str>WROX</str>
    </arr>      
</doc>
```

I am using linq to populate a "Product" class. I am able to select the elements by position, however this becomes a problem if the node doesn't exist. Is there a way to select a node based on the value of its attribute? In the below example, can I get the arr node if the @name attribute = "ATR_FamilyName"? In xpath it would be:

```
doc/arr[@name = 'ATR_FamilyName']/str
```

here is my linq to xml query:

```
var query = from rt in results
    where (String)rt.Descendants().ElementAt(5).Element("str").Value == "0"
    select new Product.Product
        {
            FamilyName = (String)rt.Descendants().ElementAt(3).Value
            // doc/arr[@name = 'ATR_FamilyName']/str - select Family Name is arr/@name 'ATR_FamilyName'                              
            MorePropertiestoset....                              
        };
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like AS-CII's answer, but without using a query expression (except for the outer one), and with the cast for `XAttribute`, and selecting the `str` element value inside an anonymous type:

```
select new Product.Product
{
    FamilyName = rt.Descendants("arr")
                   .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "ATR_FamilyName")
                   .Select(x => (string) x.Element("str"))
                   .FirstOrDefault(),
    MorePropertiesToSet....                              
};
```

Note that the use of a cast for the result of the call to `Attribute("name")` means that if there are any elements which *don't* have the attribute, the cast will result in a null reference (which isn't equal to the string literal). If you use the `Value` property, you'll get an exception. Sometimes an exception may be better - if that indicates that the data is fundamentally broken and you want to find out about it rather than just not match the value.

(The same is true for the cast of the `XElement` to `string`.)

Comment: Thx for the explanation on the casting, Jon. I was running into situations where not all nodes had the attribute and it was throwing an exception because I used .Value instead of the cast; this fidex it.

Answer (score 6):

With LINQ you can easily select just the nodes that have a specified attribute, like this:

```
var query = from node in results.Descendants("arr") // I believe you could use results.Elements("arr") here
            where node.Attribute("name").Value == "ATR_FamilyName"
            select new Product
            {
                FamilyName = node.Element("str").Value
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `XElement` like this:

```
from rt in results.descendants("<node name>")
where rt.attribute(attribute name).value == "specified value"
select rt
```

Sorry for typing from cell phone

Answer (score 1):

With `rt` being your respective XElement root, you could also just use the extension method [XPathSelectElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelement?view=net-7.0) like so:

`rt.XPathSelectElement("descendant::arr[@name = 'ATR_FamilyName']/str")`