# Taking from XML whole node with LINQ c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

hi this is my xml i want to get only those menuitems which has type = "0". please help. AS you see there is menuitem in menuitem and in menuitem . i want to check all of them and if type is 0 i want to get that .

i want C# code

```html
<Menu>
  <menuitem alias="CB6CF9A26E92FB60487B538C57FDD0E9" slot="0" type="1" name="თანხის შეტანა">
    <menuitem alias="5A8B27411D011CBE2EAB916A9E6E7B4C" slot="0" type="1" name="ბარათი">
      <menuitem alias="B82505AC178863EFF64260EC52E410BE" slot="0" type="0" name="მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი|VISA CLASSIC|GE****************0082|GEL" />
      <menuitem alias="F0CF0D9A4D732C2026948FC34DFAC29F" slot="1" type="0" name="მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი|VISA CLASSIC|GE****************0082|USD|კურსი - 2.49" />
      <menuitem alias="6F6CA87FBACC28E8E5D09E29577B8E2A" slot="2" type="0" name="ცენტრალური ფილიალი|MC STANDARD|GE****************0006|GEL" />
      <menuitem alias="329078EA8197E4F153B1B562EA07CD20" slot="3" type="0" name="ცენტრალური ფილიალი|MC STANDARD|GE****************0006|USD|კურსი - 2.49" />
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem alias="2BC77B16A194A82BF55AC48966CE6141" slot="1" type="1" name="შემნახველი">
      <menuitem alias="7B0B015673196CC9FFB4D685B6448410" slot="0" type="0" name="მარჯანიშვილის ფილიალი|ჩემი სეიფი|GE****************0018|GEL" />
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem alias="1FC50E2144F4DF526D9ABCB45A078547" slot="2" type="1" name="ჩემი სეიფი - IBS(კოდი 3331)" />
  </menuitem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: please provide us with example of xml /code you have tried

Comment: i have edited my question sr for mistake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to XML selecting a node bases on a attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892488/linq-to-xml-selecting-a-node-bases-on-a-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1):

```
 newDocument.SelectNodes("//Menu//menuitem[@type='0']")
```

this helped me .

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.